# Stop command prompt from opening when running exe file built from haskell project

Tags: windows, haskell, build, exe, cabal

I have created a small application that uses the gloss library for a GUI. When typing "cabal run [cabal file]" the project is built and run, and only prompts the GUI. When I instead go and click on the .exe file that was generated from the build, the GUI opens but so does the command prompt. I want to stop the command prompt from opening and only have the window from gloss open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default on Windows GHC builds console programs, which open a Command Prompt terminal if one isn’t open already. If you want to build a GUI-only program, you can pass `-mwindow` to the linker by giving the `-optl -mwindow` flag to GHC. If you’re using Cabal, you would add this flag to the `ghc-options` field in the executable stanza.

Beware that if you use this flag, your program will not have any `stdin`, `stdout`, or `stderr` file handles, so actions like `putStrLn`, `print`, and `getLine` will not work, since they’re equivalent to `hPutStrLn stdout`, `hPrint stdout`, and `hGetLine stdin`. If you want to do any logging or printing, you’ll need to open a handle yourself (e.g. a file, terminal, or socket with another program reading the other end); however, `Debug.Trace` will still work if you need temporary tracing for debugging.

You can find more helpful reference information in the [GHC User’s Guide §16. Running GHC on Win32 Systems](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/win32-dlls.html#running-ghc-on-win32-systems).

Comment: This worked, I just had to put `ghc-options:` under executable [package_name] in my .cabal file. And give it  `-optl-mwindows` as the parameter!